# nuget get different versions swicth

Tags: nservicebus, nuget

I am trying to nuget the new 3.0 binaries for NServiceBus but they don't seem to be available in package manager.

Is there a switch to force nuget to get the latest available version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3.0 line is in pre-release at the moment, so you'll have to do:

```
PM> Install-Package NServiceBus -Pre
```

At the time of this answer, it will install RC5.

The switch `-Pre` is short for `-PreRelease`, which will install a pre-release version if it's more recent than the latest stable. If a stable version is more recent, it will install the stable. See this [NServiceBus page on nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus/3.0.0-rc5). For details on prerelease on nuget, see the [versioning page](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning).

You can also try the continuous integration (CI) package:

```
PM> Install-Package NServiceBus-CI
```